Gazebo installation problems
I am really new to robotics so I was following this tutorial on how to install Gazebo for ROS2 Jazzy: https://github.com/husarion/rosbot_ros/tree/jazzy I get an error during rosdep install. The whole installation process is described below. I want to know how to fix the error I get and how to successfully install Gazebo with the husarion rosbot.
So it looked like this:
> sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip ros-dev-tools
> stm32flash

I already have ros2_ws directory so I did this:
cd ros2_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/husarion/rosbot_ros 

Since I want to build and run Gazebo simulation, I skipped the hardware part. Then I installed the Gazebo Harmonic version compatible with ROS2 Jazzy following the guide on the official Gazebo site: https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/install_ubuntu/
I put the following line in the .bashrc file and sourced it.
export GZ_VERSION=harmonic

For building I did this:
export HUSARION_ROS_BUILD=simulation

source /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash

vcs import src < src/rosbot/rosbot_hardware.repos
vcs import src < src/rosbot/rosbot_simulation.repos

# Build only diff_drive_controller and imu_sensor_broadcaster from ros2_controllers
cp -r src/ros2_controllers/diff_drive_controller src && cp -r src/ros2_controllers/imu_sensor_broadcaster src && rm -rf src/ros2_controllers

sudo rosdep init
rosdep update --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO

However, I get an error when executing the following lines:
rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO -y
colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

It says this:
WARNING: Skipping /usr/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/pybind11-2.11.1.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
WARNING: Skipping /usr/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/pybind11-2.11.1.dist-info due to invalid metadata entry 'name'
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rosbot_gazebo: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [ign_ros2_control]

Edit:
This was solved based on the first answer using:
git clone https://github.com/husarion/rosbot_ros -b jazzy

However, now I had the problems with the previous line since it doesn't find the mentioned files:
cp -r src/ros2_controllers/diff_drive_controller src && cp -r src/ros2_controllers/imu_sensor_broadcaster src && rm -rf src/ros2_controllers

Then I used the diff_drive_controller and imu_sensor_broadcaster from the previous run before cloning the jazzy branch. I could continue with
rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO -y

But in the last line:
colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

I get the following error in the test_imu_sensor_broadcaster:
error: no matching function for call to ‘FriendIMUSensorBroadcaster::init(const char [28], const std::string&)’

error: no matching function for call to ‘hardware_interface::ResourceManager::ResourceManager(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’

Is this maybe due to copying the ros2 controllers based on files defined in not the jazzy branch? Is there any way how to install the correct version since when I clone the jazzy branch and follow the guide, there is no ros2 controller?

The package was renamed from iron on, instead of ign_ros2_control it is called gz_ros2_control on jazzy. See the README for supported combinations.
It seems that the husarion repository has a jazzy branch where this is fixed:
git clone https://github.com/husarion/rosbot_ros -b jazzy


Thank you very much. This helped me get further in the guide. Unfortunately, now I get another error later in the last command so I edited the questions. If you have time, could you please check it out?

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, what that copying and removing is about.
Just follow our "official" installation guidelines and build the whole stack or install binaries.
